RDA Enrollments not triggering EES Event
We have the Banno integration done and we are successfully getting EES messages from Banno. There is supposed to be an event that is triggered when someone enrolls for mobile deposit. These are coming in, we get a few a day, however in Banno back-office there are several RDA enrollments that we see that aren't triggering an EES event. Do only certain enrollments trigger the EES event?
I cannot determine the difference between the enrollments that trigger EES events and those that do not, which appears to be most of them.

The short answer is yes, only certain enrollments trigger an EES event.
Here are some examples of EES Banno events - https://jackhenry.dev/open-enterprise-api-docs/enterprise-event-system/tutorials/event-examples/banno-110000/
In the future we may publish a list of all enrollments that trigger EES events, but we do not have anything at this time.

Hi Sam, thank you for linking the examples, but this does not help me. So not all RDA enrollments trigger an EES event and there isn't an explanation why? What is the point of having the RDA enrollment workflow?

RDA enrollment itself does not trigger an EES event, however when a user deposits a check using remote deposit capture it will create an event (https://jackhenry.dev/open-enterprise-api-docs/enterprise-event-system/tutorials/event-examples/banno-110000/110020-event-samples/).
